# Who is the Earth Bender in the OP?

Tags: avatar

In the opening of *Avatar: The Last Airbender* when we see Benders of each element we see that

Air = Aang
Fire = Azula
Water = Pakku

but i don't seem to recall who the Earth Bender is. they look too manly to be Toph and loo too young and sane to be Boomi. so i am wondering who is this Earth Bender

Comment: [Haru](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Haru), perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His name is [Sud](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sud)

Just compare this images

[image: Sud]

[image: Opening]

btw he was the first result in google search :)

Comment: He was Avatar Roku's earthbending teacher from the flashbacks. He was also the original inspirations for Toph.